# Calculating Averages of every 6th cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to calculate the average of a series of cells across multiple tables on the same spreadsheet.

Each manager has a table and in each table, there are a number of statistics e.g. Total Activity, Outbound Calls & Credit. Each table is situated one under the other e.g. Danny's table might be situated on rows 1- 5, Ann's 7-12, Katie's 14-19. I need to find the average for each statistic and output it to my summary page.

I've tried using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Average` but could not get it working as the range is scattered among various rows. I do however know that each variable appears in every 6th row so I tried `For i = 2 To lastRow Step 6` which outputted the values into cells and calculated the averages based on that cell range but I'd rather have something more direct if possible.

Could anyone offer a valid solution to this?

Sample of data beneath. looking to get the average for each of the 4 variables.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what your data look like? By the way, what about the `subtotals` basic Excel feature?

Comment: Edited. I wasn't aware that you could do this on VBA?

Comment: [Using Excel worksheet functions in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/events-worksheetfunctions-shapes/using-excel-worksheet-functions-in-visual-basic)    and [WorksheetFunction object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction)

Comment: Everything you can do in Excel, can be done in VBA. For that, you can record a macro while you perform your action, and the macro recording will create the VBA macro for you. More information can be found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative 1

If there are other values than the values you want an average of in column B, you can use **SUMPRODUCT**.

Enter this formula in any cell in any other column than column B. It will calculate an average of every 6th value starting on row 2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B*1*NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))*(MOD(ROW(B:B),6)=2))/SUMPRODUCT(1*NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))*(MOD(ROW(B:B),6)=2))
```

- `B:B`                   Array of all values in column.
- `1*NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))`   Array of 1 or 0, 1 on non blank cells in column B, 0 for blank cells.
- `1*(MOD(ROW(B:B),6)=2)` Array of 1 or 0, 1 on row 2, 8, 14 and so fourth

`SUMPRODUCT(B:B*1*NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))*(MOD(ROW(B:B),6)=2))` sums all non blank cells in column B on every 6th cell starting at row 2.
`SUMPRODUCT(1*NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))*(MOD(ROW(B:B),6)=2))` counts all non blank cells in column B on every 6th cell starting at row 2.

To speed up the formula you can replace **B:B** with for example **B1:B100** depending of the number of rows that have values.

### Alternative 2

If there are nothing but values you want an average of, then you can use **SUBTOTAL** as suggested by Dominique. `=SUBTOTAL(1,B:B)`